# Which is the most efficient algorithm for multiple-precision multiplication?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, c++-cli, integer-arithmetic

I'm working on a native C++/CLI class which performs integer arithmetic with multiple-precision values. Individual integers are represented by arrays of 64-bit unsigned integers. The sign is represented by a boolean value, negative values are stored with their absolute values, not as two's complements. This makes dealing with sign issues much easier. Currently I'm optimizing the multiplication operation. I've already done several optimization rounds, but still my function requires **twice the time of the * operator of two .NET BigInteger values**, which shows that there's still considerable potential for further optimization.

Before asking for help, let me show you what I've already tried. My first attempt was a naive approach: Multiply pairs of all 64-bit items using an elementary 64-to-128-bit multiplication, and shift/add the results. I don't show the code here, because it was terribly slow. The next attempt was a **recursive divide-and-conquer algorithm**, which turned out to be much better. In my implementation, both operands are split recursively in the middle, until two 64-bit values remain. These are multiplied yielding a 128-bit result. The collected elementary results are shift/added all the way up the recursion layers to yield the final result. This algorithm probably benefits from the fact that much less 64-to-128-bit elementary products need to be computed, which seems to be the main bottleneck.

So here's my code. The first snippet shows the top-level entry point:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Multi-precision multiplication, using a recursive divide-and-conquer plan:
// Left  split: (a*2^k + b)i = ai*2^k + bi
// Right split: a(i*2^k + j) = ai*2^k + aj

public: static UINT64* Mul (UINT64* pu8Factor1,
                            UINT64* pu8Factor2,
                            UINT64  u8Length1,
                            UINT64  u8Length2,
                            UINT64& u8Product)
    {
    UINT64* pu8Product;

    if ((u8Length1 > 0) && (u8Length2 > 0))
        {
        pu8Product = _SnlMemory::Unsigned ((u8Length1 * u8Length2) << 1);

        u8Product  = Mul (pu8Product, pu8Factor1, 0, u8Length1,
                                      pu8Factor2, 0, u8Length2);
        }
    else
        {
        pu8Product = _SnlMemory::Unsigned (0);
        u8Product  = 0;
        }
    return pu8Product;
    }
```

The factors are passed in as `UINT64*` array pointers, with the lengths specified separately as number of `UINT64` items in the respective array. The function allocates a memory block big enough to hold a value of the maximum expected length, which is used as a scratchpad for temporary subordinate results, too. The function calls another `Mul` function that performs the recursive evaluation and returns the number of `UINT64` items actually used by the final result.

This is the recursive "divide" part of the divide-and-conquer algorithm:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Recursively expand the arbitrary-precision multiplication to the sum of a
// series of elementary 64-to-128-bit multiplications.

private: static UINT64 Mul (UINT64* pu8Product,
                            UINT64* pu8Factor1,
                            UINT64  u8Offset1,
                            UINT64  u8Length1,
                            UINT64* pu8Factor2,
                            UINT64  u8Offset2,
                            UINT64  u8Length2)
    {
    UINT64 *pu8Lower, u8Lower, *pu8Upper, u8Upper, u8Split;
    UINT64 u8Product = 0;

    if (u8Length1 > 1)
        {
        // left split: (a*2^k + b)i = ai*2^k + bi
        u8Split = u8Length1 >> 1;

        u8Lower = Mul (pu8Lower = pu8Product,
                       pu8Factor1, u8Offset1, u8Split,  // bi
                       pu8Factor2, u8Offset2, u8Length2);

        u8Upper = Mul (pu8Upper = pu8Product + ((u8Split * u8Length2) << 1),
                       pu8Factor1, u8Offset1 + u8Split, // ai
                                   u8Length1 - u8Split,
                       pu8Factor2, u8Offset2, u8Length2);

        u8Product = Mul (u8Split, pu8Lower, u8Lower, pu8Upper, u8Upper);
        }
    else if (u8Length2 > 1)
        {
        // right split: a(i*2^k + j) = ai*2^k + aj
        u8Split = u8Length2 >> 1;

        u8Lower = Mul (pu8Lower = pu8Product,
                       pu8Factor1, u8Offset1, u8Length1, // aj
                       pu8Factor2, u8Offset2, u8Split);

        u8Upper = Mul (pu8Upper = pu8Product + ((u8Length1 * u8Split) << 1),
                       pu8Factor1, u8Offset1, u8Length1, // ai
                       pu8Factor2, u8Offset2 + u8Split,
                                   u8Length2 - u8Split);

        u8Product = Mul (u8Split, pu8Lower, u8Lower, pu8Upper, u8Upper);
        }
    else // recursion base: 64-to-128-bit multiplication
        {
        AsmMul1 (pu8Factor1 [u8Offset1],
                 pu8Factor2 [u8Offset2],
                 u8Lower, u8Upper);

        if (u8Upper > 0)
            {
            pu8Product [u8Product++] = u8Lower;
            pu8Product [u8Product++] = u8Upper;
            }
        else if (u8Lower > 0)
            {
            pu8Product [u8Product++] = u8Lower;
            }
        }
    return u8Product;
    }
```

In the first conditional branch, the left operand is split. In the second one, the right operand is split. The third branch is the recursion base, which calls the elementary multiplication routine:

```
; -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
; 64-bit to 128-bit multiplication, using the x64 MUL instruction

AsmMul1 proc ; ?AsmMul1@@$$FYAX_K0AEA_K1@Z

; ecx  : Factor1
; edx  : Factor2
; [r8] : ProductL
; [r9] : ProductH

mov  rax, rcx            ; rax = Factor1
mul  rdx                 ; rdx:rax = Factor1 * Factor2
mov  qword ptr [r8], rax ; [r8] = ProductL
mov  qword ptr [r9], rdx ; [r9] = ProductH
ret

AsmMul1 endp
```

This is a simple ASM PROC which uses the CPU MUL instruction for 64-to-128-bit multiplication. I've tried several other candidates in ASM and C++, and this one was the most efficient one.

The final part is the "conquer" part of the divide-and-conquer algorithm:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Shift-add recombination of the results of two partial multiplications.

private: static UINT64 Mul (UINT64  u8Split,
                            UINT64* pu8Lower,
                            UINT64  u8Lower,
                            UINT64* pu8Upper,
                            UINT64  u8Upper)
    {
    FLAG   fCarry;
    UINT64 u8Count, u8Lower1, u8Upper1;
    UINT64 u8Product = u8Lower;

    if (u8Upper > 0)
        {
        u8Count = u8Split + u8Upper;
        fCarry  = false;

        for (u8Product = u8Split; u8Product < u8Count; u8Product++)
            {
            u8Lower1 = u8Product < u8Lower ? pu8Lower [u8Product] : 0;
            u8Upper1 = pu8Upper [u8Product - u8Split];

            if (fCarry)
                {
                pu8Lower [u8Product] = u8Lower1 + u8Upper1 + 1;
                fCarry = u8Lower1 >= MAX_UINT64 - u8Upper1;
                }
            else
                {
                pu8Lower [u8Product] = u8Lower1 + u8Upper1;
                fCarry = u8Lower1 > MAX_UINT64 - u8Upper1;
                }
            }
        if (fCarry)
            {
            pu8Lower [u8Product++] = 1;
            }
        }
    return u8Product;
    }
```

Here two partial results are added, with the second operand shifted left by the "split factor" of the corresponding recursion step.

I've spent considerable time optimizing the code for speed, with quite some success, but now I've reached a point where I don't see any further possibilities, except for using a completely different algorithm. However, since I'm not an expert on numeric tricks, I'm stuck here.

Hoping for some cool ideas on how to improve this calculation...

**EDIT 2019-03-26:** Well, sometimes it seems to be better not to try to be smart... after several additional optimization attempts, some of them even moderately successful, I tried to write a real dumb version of the multiplication that simply exploits the computational power of the `_umul128` and `_addcarry_u64` compiler intrinsics. The code is utmost simple:

```
public: static UINT64* Mul (UINT64* pu8Factor1,
                            UINT64* pu8Factor2,
                            UINT64  u8Length1,
                            UINT64  u8Length2,
                            UINT64& u8Product)
    {
    u8Product = u8Length1 + u8Length2;

    CHAR    c1Carry1, c1Carry2;
    UINT64  u8Offset, u8Offset1, u8Offset2, u8Item1, u8Item2, u8Lower, u8Upper;
    UINT64* pu8Product = _SnlMemory::Unsigned (u8Product);

    if (u8Product > 0)
        {
        for (u8Offset1 = 0; u8Offset1 < u8Length1; u8Offset1++)
            {
            u8Offset = u8Offset1;
            u8Item1  = pu8Factor1 [u8Offset1];
            u8Item2  = 0;
            c1Carry1 = 0;
            c1Carry2 = 0;

            for (u8Offset2 = 0; u8Offset2 < u8Length2; u8Offset2++)
                {
                u8Lower = _umul128 (u8Item1, pu8Factor2 [u8Offset2], &u8Upper);

                c1Carry1 = _addcarry_u64 (c1Carry1, u8Item2, u8Lower,
                                          &u8Item2);

                c1Carry2 = _addcarry_u64 (c1Carry2, u8Item2,
                                          pu8Product  [u8Offset],
                                          pu8Product + u8Offset);
                u8Item2 = u8Upper;
                u8Offset++;
                }
            if (c1Carry1 != 0)
                {
                c1Carry2 = _addcarry_u64 (c1Carry2, u8Item2 + 1,
                                          pu8Product  [u8Offset],
                                          pu8Product + u8Offset);
                }
            else if (u8Item2 != 0)
                {
                c1Carry2 = _addcarry_u64 (c1Carry2, u8Item2,
                                          pu8Product  [u8Offset],
                                          pu8Product + u8Offset);
                }
            }
        if (pu8Product [u8Product - 1] == 0)
            {
            u8Product--;
            }
        }
    return pu8Product;
    }
```

It creates a result buffer on the heap, large enough to hold the maximum size of the product, and does elementary 64-zo-128-bit `_umul128` multiplications in two nested loops in combination with two streams of ripple-carry additions using `_addcarry_u64`. The performance of this version is by far the best of everything I've tried so far! It is about 10 times faster than the equivalent .NET BigInteger multiplication, so in the end I've achieved a speed-up by factor 20.

Comment: It sounds like you're still using the naive O(n^2) algorithm, currently the most efficient algorithm is O(n log n) https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02070778/document Which algorithm is best depends on how large your numbers are but you could at least try Karatsuba

Comment: @Joni Thanks for the link. Seems to be heavy reading for someone not too deep into mathematics, but I'll try to understand it. I've already tried **Karatsuba**, which is usually applied inside a divide-and-conquer recursion, too, but it was slower than the usual straightforward four-multiplication variant. The main problem with Karatsuba is that it requires two carry bits in one temporary computation, which seems to annihilate the benefit of saving one multiplication.

Comment: @Joni By the way, the numbers I have to deal with are around 4096 bits long (i.e. 64 x 64-bit quantities). However, multiplication should work efficiently with larger values, too, e.g. 16384 bits.

Comment: btw for modular multiplication (esp. in the context of modexp) there are some specific techniques, so if that's what you use this for then it changes everything

Comment: @harold In fact, **ModExp** is something that I will need later, but I'm still busy optimizing the basic arithmetic functions. Multiplication works now decently, using `_addcarry_u64` instead of clumsy C++ code or an ASM call improved the performance by about 25%. Maybe I'll post another question here when it comes to ModExp'ing. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can see in the [reference source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Numerics/System/Numerics/BigIntegerBuilder.cs#L610), BigInteger in .NET uses a fairly slow multiplication algorithm, the usual quadratic time algorithm using 32x32->64 multiplies. But it is written with low overhead: iterative, few allocations, and no calls to non-inlinable ASM procedures. Partial products are added into the result immediately rather than materialized separately.

The non-inlinable ASM procedure can be replaced with the [_umul128](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/umul128?view=vs-2017) intrinsic. The manual carry calculations (both the conditional `+1` and determining the output carry) can be replaced by the `_addcarry_u64` intrinsic.

Fancier algorithms such as Karatsuba multiplication and Toom-Cook multiplication can be effective, but not when the recursion is done all the way down to the single limb level - that is far past the point where the overhead outweighs the saved elementary multiplications. As a concrete example, [this implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java) of Java's BigInteger switches to Karatsuba for 80 limbs (2560 bits because they use 32 bit limbs), and to 3-way Toom-Cook for 240 limbs. Given that threshold of 80, with only 64 limbs I would not expect too much gain there anyway, if any.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details about the .NET and Java implementations. Very interesting! As far as I understand the Toom-Cook algorithm, what I'm basically doing on each recursion step is a Toom-1.5 split. Is this correct? I wonder if it would be better to do a Toom-2 split, i.e. split both operands simultaneously on each recursion level. However, this would require four invocations of the next recursive step, instead of four, and it would require the recombination of four subordinate results instead of two as well. I'm not sure if this would turn out faster.

Comment: @SBS well Toom-1.5 is essentially useless: just implement long-multiplication, also quadratic time but less overhead. Toom-2 sure, but it wouldn't be the case that "it is faster", rather, it *becomes faster* for large enough inputs, where that threshold is will depend on how efficient your long-multiplication and Toom-2 steps are.

Comment: @SBS BTW I noticed that you'd had some trouble with `_umul128`, which I still recommend, I don't quite get the issue: it compiles [really well](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/CWVA0w) - there's nothing in the manual version that would make it better than this. If the trouble persists then I would actually recommend writing the entire inner long multiplication in ASM, to avoid excessive calls and to avoid store/loading the results of the `mul`

Comment: Yes, I had a problem with _umul128, or actually with generics in general, and calls into ASM routines, too. It turned out to be an issue specific to C++/CLI, because in this context, my C++ functions are compiled to MSIL by default, and as soon as machine code needs to be included, in the form of an instrinsic or a call to an ASM routine, some automatic function call thunking kicks in, which steals a lot of performance. I've resolved this issue in the meantime by forcing the compiler to generate native code instead of MSIL, which eliminates the thunking at the scope of my native class.

Comment: It seems to me that most of the potential for optimization still resides in the elimination of overhead. I did some tests right now, replacing the ripple-carry addition in the "conquer" part by an ASM routine, which makes use of the CPU ADC instruction. The gain, however, was not impressing - somewhere around 5%. Anyway, I consider choosing your answer as the accepted one, because it contained some important clues. I'll just wait a little bit if other answers rush in - which is not quite probable, however.

Comment: I've marked your answer as "accepted", not because it was the only one, but because it gave me important insights. So it seems that multiplication of values around 64 limbs doesn't benefit from fancy algorithms like **Toom-Cook** and **Karatsuba**, and my focus should be on the elimination of more overhead in my code instead. The `_addcarry_u64` intrinsic was an interesting hint, I'll search for more tricks of this kind. Moreover, I'll try to implement **Toom-2** in my recursive function, just to see if it pays off. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I implemented Karatsuba-Offman as a recursive subroutine that did successive split-in-two and it was far quicker than the standard long multiplication method.
Stop the 2:1-split when you reach a length for which there is a hardware muliplier of course! You can also do parallel processing by mulithreading on a two or more core machine.